# The response.setheader on a java servlet does not disable browser cache

Tags: java, jquery, html

*What I am trying to do*

Goal
 1.  Not allow the browser to cache responses from the server
 2. After session logout the back button should not bring the user to a cached page

*What I have done so far*

In my web app, i have a login page that authenticates a user and then routes to another page via the Login servlet. In the Login servlet I have set the response header to not cache the html pages. This does not work.

Currently I  use the below in the doPost method of the Login servlet

```
response.setHeader("Cache-control","no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
response.setHeader("max-age", "-1");
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
```

*Results*
The html page header (from google chrome dev tools ) shows this

> Accept-Ranges:bytes Content-Length:8404 Content-Type:text/html
>   Date:Sat, 16 Jan 2016 22:26:57 GMT ETag:W/"8404-1452983191066"
>   Last-Modified:Sat, 16 Jan 2016 22:26:31 GMT Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Any suggestions people.. Thanks in advance for you time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1341133/4796021

Comment: Thanks . I did try that but does not seem to work. Also does this work when we make a ajax call from a html page and the response from the server is set not to cache?

Answer (score 0):

Writing only `response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");` worked for me.

Tried running my Java application on Chrome and Edge, and the back button showed no signs of caching with the above line of code.

I used `Http 1.2` in my application.